# spaceflight physical -- what exactly does "physical" mean in that context?

Tags: meaning

Source: [This Week in Space: Help Wanted on Bone-Dry Mars](https://www.yahoo.com/tech/this-week-in-space-help-wanted-on-bone-dry-mars-204819725.html)

Example:

> But NASA isn’t turning this into some kind of space-based reality show: The qualifications to be an astronaut candidate are still pretty specific. You need a science degree (ideally an advanced one), three years of related professional experience, or 1,000 hours of pilot-in-command time in a jet aircraft. And couch potatoes, take note, you also “must pass the NASA long-duration **spaceflight physical**.”

In the dictionary, the word physical has several meanings. Which one is used here?

Comment: [***physical***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/physical) def. 6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Physical* as a noun (*a physical*, *his physical*, and so forth) is a very common way of naming a ***physical examination***: an examination, usually under medical direction, of the examinee's physical fitness.

> I just took a physical for a job. Will high blood pressure be held against me? —[Yahoo Questions](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20151016122016AAs1PEl)
>
> Four days before preseason opener against the Green Bay Packers, the New England Patriots elected to release Matt Flynn. [...] "Matt never passed his physical," the head coach said. —[247Sports](http://nep.247sports.com/Bolt/Bill-Belichick-Matt-Flynn-never-passed-his-physical-38659884)
>
> During the Vietnam War, Biden got a draft notice but flunked the physical due to asthma. —[Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2007/dec/21/fact-sheet-who-has-served-military/)

Answer (score 5):

A *physical*, when used in this context is a medical examination. This examination is used to make sure that you are healthy enough to go into space without illness, injury or death.

The word *physical* is used with same meaning for most (if not all) paramilitary and military organisations.

Comment: _"The word physical is used with same meaning for most (if not all) paramilitary and military organisations"_ ....and as one of the requirements for sending your child back to elementary school at the end of the summer, at least where I live.

Comment: @Adam The school needs a physical? Hm never heard of that before :D

Comment: I think it is "only" required for children who will participate in the after-school sports offerings or go on any of the field trips - so effectively everyone needs one.